# Can i get nagios to check the health of my website?

Tags: nagios

I notice that one of my sites wasnt working properly and was giving me 500 errors. Nagios didn't catch it because the HTTP server was still working.

Is there a way i can tell nagios to check the health of my site?
I think i'll just write a script which pings certain pages and make a cronjob for it. On error i'd get an email so thats my suitable replacement for the moment will be.

I am running debian linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use the **check_http** plugin that is part nagios-plugins package.
it can monitor http status of the site and can monitor other http parameters as well.

Comment: The check_http plugin also supports checking for specific string which can be useful.

Comment: Cool, i added this in. I am a nagios noob. How do i know if this worked? i put the below in commands.cfg and restarted nagios. How long do i have to wait? I put all the sites i wanted to check and one invalid site so i can get a report or something down. I added this-> define command{
 command_name check_http-MySite
 command_line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H MySite.com
}

Answer (score 2):

If you want to monitor certain page, and you know the expected status, as @Frank mentioned, `check_http` plugin can do this:

```
check_http -H domain.com -u URI -e 200
HTTP OK: Status line output matched "200" - 4886 bytes in 0.007 second response time |time=0.007446s;;;0.000000 size=4886B;;;0
```

But if you want to get alerts whenever a page returns the 500 error, I think you can monitor the Apache's access log with [check_logfiles](http://labs.consol.de/lang/de/nagios/check_logfiles/) plugin:

```
check_logfiles --tag=500 --logfile=/var/log/httpd/access_log --criticalpattern="HTTP/1.1\" 500"
```